# Binary rejected Appstore

Tags: xcode, flutter

I submitted my flutter app(quiz type) to appstore but there is no crash when I tested it. They tell me there is a problem when they try to sign up , press Ok , or when the app is launching. Do you have any idea how I can resolve this issue? if in Xcode when I run it , it works without any crash.
[image]

Comment: We can't possibly provide any concrete advice for you with the limited information you've provided. What does the symbolicated crash report indicate? [ask]

Comment: Try it on a real device, in stall from testflight.